# Custom template for the store language

Tags: blocks, multistore, custom, language, footer

I have a store with 2 languages arabic and english, and I want a phtml for arabic and another one for english

Can I do something like:

```
    <ar>
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="setTemplate">  
                <template>page/html/footer_ar.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </ar>
```

and

```
    <en>
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="setTemplate">  
                <template>page/html/footer_en.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </en>
```

the store code is `base`, english is `default` and arabic is `eg_ar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento  is **create unique Handler receptively** each store **whenever frontend page is rendered.**

Handler format is  `STORE_YOURCURRENTSTORECODE`

See at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class on function `addActionLayoutHandles`

```
$update->addHandle('STORE_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());
```

That means whenever `arabic  and english` store are rendered then create

`STORE_en` &  `STORE_ar`  handler respectively

Now just change the handler

- ar to `STORE_ar`

and

- end `STORE_en`

  `<STORE_ar>
      <reference name="footer">
          <action method="setTemplate">

              <template>page/html/footer_ar.phtml</template>
          </action>
      </reference>
  </STORE_ar>`

**and**

`<STORE_en>
    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="setTemplate">

            <template>page/html/footer_en.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</STORE_en>`

Hope this will resolved the issue.